# I can't add Point to List

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I had a List of Point, And I need to add a Point class to the list but when I tried to do this I got this error

> 'Point' is not a subtype of type 'Point' of 'value'

```
class Object {
  List<Point> coordinates = List();
  void get moveDown {
    var next = coordinates.last.y - 1;
    coordinates.add(Point(coordinates.last.x,next));
    coordinates.removeAt(0);
  }
{
```

ERROR

```
    E/flutter (21540): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Point<num>' is not a subtype of type 'Point<int>' of 'value'
E/flutter (21540): #0      List.add (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart)
E/flutter (21540): #1      Object.moveDown (package:snake/object.dart:16:17)
E/flutter (21540): #2      _MyHomePageState.logic (package:snake/main.dart:178:22)
E/flutter (21540): #3      _MyHomePageState.start.frame.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:snake/main.dart:148:11)
```

Comment: You may want to try to explicitly declare type of `Point`: it can be either `Point<int>` or `Point<double>` depending on kind of numbers you expect as coordinates.

So changing the second line to
`List<Point<int>> coordinates = List<Point<int>>();`
should do it for you. By the way, could you clarify what task you're trying to solve?

Comment: Another thing is that using `void get` seems unnatural. Getters are supposed to return a value and not supposed to perform mutations. I'd suggest to change it to `void moveDown()`